# Template operator returning a reference to an abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, operators, abstract-class

Fellas, why won't this code work?

```
template <typename t>
class Abstract
{
public:
   ~Abstract(){}
   virtual Abstract<t>& operator +(Abstract<t>&) = 0;
};

template <typename t>
class Not_Abstract : public Abstract
{
t* tab; //let Not_Abstract store an array of objects of type t, whatever
public:
  ~Not_Abstract(){ delete[] tab; }
  Not_Abstract<t>& operator +(Not_Abstact<t>&);
};
```

I though that since reference is a pointer then, I don't know, both operator's definitions are equivalent; yet they seem to be separate functions. Is there anything that can be done to retain virtual operator in "Abstract" and still have the code functioning?

Comment: The compiler should give a clear error. Edit: Clang gives *error: expected class name* on the `Not_Abstract` declaration line. That's not crystal clear, but `Abstract` is a template, not a class. Apart from that, a simple typo is a clear error and it compiles otherwise. Not sure what problem you're having.

Comment: We're not _Fellas_ we're *coders*. Entirely different. :)

Comment: @chris You might want to spell it out explicitly: they should inherit from `Abstract<t>`.

Comment: Minus 1: Please post code that actually demonstrates the problem you have.  The above code fails to compile on a completely different line.  If you fix this problem, let me know and I will reverse the minus 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the function in the derived class be an implementation of the virtual member function in the base class, it has to be declared such that the argument type remains unchanged:

```
Not_Abstract<t>& operator +(Abstact<t>&);
```

If you want to make sure that you are dealing with an instance of `Non_Abstract` as the RHS of the operator, you have to perform a `dynamic_cast` in the implementation of the function.

```
template <typename t>
Not_Abstract<t>& Not_Abstract<T>::operator +(Abstact<t>& rhsBase)
{
   Not_Abstract<t>& rhs = dynamic_cast<Not_Abstract<t>&>(rhsBase);
   // ... Now work with a Not_Abstract object
   // ....

}
```

If `rhsBase` cannot be cast to `Not_Abstract<t>&`, `dynamic_cast` will throw a `std::bad_cast` exception. Your code has to be prepared to deal with that exception being thrown.

Answer (score 3):

> both operator's definitions are equivalent

No they're not. One has an `Abstract&` parameter, the other has a `Not_Abstract&` parameter. To override, the parameter types must match, so that the override can be called in the same way as the function it overrides.

> Is there anything that can be done to retain virtual operator in "Abstract" and still have the code functioning?

The override will have to take an `Abstract&`, and do the right thing whether or not it's called with a `Non_Abstract`.

Comment: So, the result has to match, but not the argument? If I changed the argument to a reference to my abstract class, I won't have the option to access it's private part, since it has none.

Comment: Wait, or the other way round? xD

Comment: @Jules: The result can be covariant - that is, the override can return a more derived type - so that's fine. The parameter has to match - virtual functions must be callable via the base class, so must be callable with any type derived from `Abstract`, not just `Not_Abstract`. You'll need either more virtual functions (perhaps something along the lines of the Visitor pattern), or `dynamic_cast`, to treat the parameter as a `Non_Abstract`.